# Concatenate a plain text string and binary data

Tags: python

My goal is create a HTTP request (headers and body) **manually**. It has to look like this:

```
Some-Header1: some value1
Some-Header2: some value2
Some-Header3: some value3

-------------MyBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content_0"; filename="123.pdf"
Content-Length: 93
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

  ==== here is the binary data of 123.pdf ====
  ==== here is the binary data of 123.pdf ====
  ==== here is the binary data of 123.pdf ====
  ==== here is the binary data of 123.pdf ====

-------------MyBoundary--
```

I've found out that this is the only way to send a file to a web service through its API  because I sniffed the traffic of a script in Ruby doing that and the it turned out to look like I've shown above.

So the headers such as "Some-Header1" and other - are the plain text headers. Notice that there is also "`-------------MyBoundary--`" after "`==== here is the binary data of 123.pdf ====`"

But "`==== here is the binary data of 123.pdf ====`" is **binary** data.

The question is, how do I chain (combine) the plain text data with the binary data?

P.S. I've been trying to achieve this by the standard libraries such a python-requests and failed. I don't consider using them again at this point. For now I only need to know how to combine the plain text and binary data.

**UPDATE**:

How can I easily embed a binary data to a string?

```
import textwrap

body_headers = textwrap.dedent(
    """
    -------------MyBoundary
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content_0"; filename="a.c"
    Content-Length: 1234
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

                    %b ??? -> to indicate that a binary data will be placed here

    -------------MyBoundary--


    """
) % binary_data" #???
```

**UPDATE2**:

```
text1 = textwrap.dedent(
    """
    -------------MyBoundary
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content_0"; filename="a.pdf"
    Content-Length: 1234
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

    replace_me

    -------------MyBoundary--


    """
)

with open("test1.pdf", "rb") as file_hander:
    binary_data = file_hander.read()

print (isinstance(binary_data, str)) # True
print (isinstance("replace_me", str)) # True

print text1.replace("replace_me", binary_data) # --> [Decode error - output not utf-8]

print text1.replace("replace_me", binary_data).encode("utf-8") # exception
```

Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 195: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And this also gives me an exception:

```
print unicode(text1.replace("replace_me", binary_data), "utf-8")
# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 195: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: @hlt, I just told you what the problem I'd run into. Code? str1 = headers; str_total = str1 + open(file_name, "rb"). --> doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks. (Please add this into the post, code in comments is a pain to find)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To load binary data from a file, you would do

```
with open(file_name, 'rb') as the_file:
    binary_data = the_file.read()
```

Now, there are two scenarios, depending on your Python version:

#### Python 2 - `unicode` and `str`

`binary_data` will be a `str`, concatenation should work perfectly fine unless your other string is `unicode`, in which case you probably should encode that (nearly no networking function requires `unicode` in Python 2):

```
normal_str = unicode_str.encode(encoding)
```

where `encoding` usually is something like `"utf-8"`, `"utf-16"` or `"latin-1"`, but it may be more exotic.

#### Python 3 - `str` and `bytes`

`binary_data` will be a `bytes` object, which you cannot simply concatenate with a default `str`. If whatever you use to send the data requires `bytes`, you follow the same encoding approach as with Python 2. If it requires `str` (which for networking purposes is probably unlikely), you must *decode* the given encoding (as this is nearly impossible to guess, you should check what encoding your file uses) using

```
normal_str = byte_str.decode(encoding)
```

again passing the encoding as an argument (**hint**: `"latin-1"` should be fine, as it preserves the bytes, while others, like `"utf-8"`, may fail on actual binary data (that is not encoded strings) [*HT to [@SergeBallesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398381/concatinate-a-plain-text-string-and-binary-data#comment39618261_25399184)*])

**To avoid this kind of trouble in Python 3**, you may wish to define your headers as `bytes` from the beginning using `something = b"whatever"` instead of `something = "whatever"` (*note the added `b`*) and open other input files to the header as binary as well. Then, simply concatenating the strings using `+` should not be a problem.

#### Sending the HTTP request

To send this kind of raw data to the server, you have different options:

- If you want more control than `urllib` (or `urllib2`) and `requests` give you, you can do low-level networking with raw sockets to send any data you like with [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/socket.html) (the [example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/socket.html#example) is a good example of how to implement this)
- You could pass the data (everything between and including `---(snip)--MyBoundary`) as request data to a `POST` request (if your HTTP request is one, which is not specified in the question) using `urllib` or `requests`

#### Efficiency

If you opt for raw sockets and send very large files, you may want to read the file in chunks (using `the_file.read(number_of_bytes)`) and write it directly to the socket (using `the_socket.send(read_binary_data)`). [HT to [*@Teudimundo*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398381/concatinate-a-plain-text-string-and-binary-data#comment39615495_25399184)]

#### Re: Update

Regarding the update (which really should be a new question...): There is no format string syntax (neither new (`"{}"`), nor old (`"%s"`)) for `bytes`. You need to use  `decode` on the `bytes` object to turn it into a string and use format strings properly (or turn the string into `bytes` with `encode` and use normal concatenation instead). Also note that `textwrap.dedent` does **not** work on `bytes`, because regular expressions do not operate on `bytes` in Python.

Comment: I was writing the same kind of answer, but I would add that instead of adding all binary data to a string, from a memory usage point of view, to read binary data in chunks and write them directly to the socket.

Comment: I have both Python2 and 3 and I've been using python-requests. Will it work if send a post like this: `session.request(....., data = binary_data_with_headers)`?

Comment: I'm not usually using `requests`, but I think you could do something with `session.post(....., data=the_data)` if your request is a POST request (make sure it is not encoded somehow). I'm not certain about what to do with GET (and other) requests. Personally, I would use raw sockets for this kind of thing

Comment: Updated. However, consider asking such follow-up questions as separate questions instead of editing your question (it makes questions and answers easier to follow for others etc.)

Comment: Nice answer, but I would'nt dare converting **binary** bytes to unicode with a multi-byte encoding as utf-8 ! It looks ok using latin1 with python 3.4 but smells like using an undocumented feature. I tried `bytes(range(256)).decode()` and it breaks with `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 128: invalid start byte`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Very true. Added that hint.

Comment: well, an error (it's related to this question), look at my update please. I'm not sure that it's working, although it might despite the error.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Use `latin-1` for binary data. `utf-8` expects certain byte sequences (see e.g. @SergeBallesta's comment and my subsequent edit)